# Single-Line to Multi-Line ES6 Fat Arrow Function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning ES6 fat arrow functions. What is the correct way to change this code, so as to be able to put another line, even `const a = 100;` in the place indicated so that I can add some more lines to this function?

```
IMAdded: (options, args) => ({
    IMAdded: {
        filter: newIM => true, *need to add another line here*
    },
}),
```

Update:

Here's ES6 code that runs:

```
const subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager({
    schema,
    pubsub,
    setupFunctions: {
        APPTAdded: (options, args) => ({
            APPTAdded: {
                filter: appointment => (true),
            },
        }),
});
```

I'd like to add some more lines into the code that returns `true`.

Comment: in **IMAdded** you have an object (not a function), you would need to do: **a:100**, then read as IMAdded.a //=> 100

Comment: If you show us the proper ES5 way to declare what you're trying to do, we can easily help you change it to ES6 with fat arrows.  With what you show now it is not clear enough what you are trying to achieve for us to know how to fix.  You have several combinations of invalid syntax and are declaring objects where we aren't sure you mean to.  So, please clarify the objective.  The most surefire way to show the objective would be to show working ES5 code for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys.  I have no idea what this would look like in ES5.  I'll update the post to show more info.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to convert the following method into having more lines:

```
{
  filter: appointment => true
}
```

You have to add curly braces and a `return` statement:

```
{
  filter: appointment => {
    // ... add your other lines here
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
filter: appointment => true,
...
```

is (and parentheses aren't needed around `true`) a shortcut for

```
filter: appointment => {
  return true;
},
...
```

which is a shortcut for

```
filter: function (appointment) {
  return true;
}.bind(this),
...
```

Any amount of lines can be added before `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

No braces or `return` needed if your function body is an expression which can span multiple lines (a *ConciseBody* in the spec)

```js
{
  filter: appointment =>
    true &&
    false
}
```

Note: I was initially confused about the question (hence the EDIT), and thought it was about *linebreaks in arrow functions in general*. And, yes, they are allowed, but only *after* the arrow.
See also the ESLint rule [`implicit-arrow-linebreak`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/implicit-arrow-linebreak), which lists this variant under "Correct code" (if configured "with the `below` option")