# Resolve Expression from Node API Endpoint (Boolean)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, session, credentials

I am trying to validate an API key to run an API endpoint function.

server.js

```
let db = require("./sql/rest_functions")            // Custom modules
let session = require("./sql/session_management")

app.get("/node/api/mssql/test", function(req, res) {
   if(session.validateKey(req)) {
     db.mssqlQuery(req, res)
   }
 })
```

session.js

```
exports.validateKey = function(req) {
  return sql.connect(config.properties)
    .then(pool => {
      return pool.request()
        .query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Login WHERE (username = '" + req.header("username") + "' AND apiKey = '" + req.header("apiKey") + "')) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(typeof response[0]['']) // returns boolean
          return response[0]['']              // return nested value to get true / false response
        })
    })
}
```

The `validateKey` function is returning true and false (I think as plain text), and I would like it to resolve to a boolean that can be passed into the API test function.

I have tried this `JSON.parse` method and the `session.validateKey(req) == 'true'` design pattern, but neither case resolves to an expected behavior.

How can I resolve the returned value to verify the user's credentials?

Comment: You should address that [SQL injection vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Also, that seems like a somewhat convoluted query to validate username/key combination: is there a reason not to simply `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE...` and then `return response[0]['COUNT(*)'] > 0` (which will give you a Boolean)?

Comment: @msanford I am working through upgrading security measures when interacting with this DB, the idea is to move towards stored procedures, but I am using the query function to test retrieval from the database during pre-production.  Thank you for the OWASP link.  I will read through it today.  I was thinking that forcing an API key match would prevent writing to the DB without proper credentials.  Am I incorrect in this assumption?

Comment: @msanford I am trying to use an apiKey like a session token and the user needs a validated apiKey to read or write.

Comment: @msanford I would like to run the ```db.mssqlQuery``` command if the user has a valid apiKey, as an added layer of protection.

Comment: @msantord Also, the docs for the mssql package for Node states that "All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection." -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: And sure, my "convoluted" comment was about the SQL query _itself:_ it's a (1) select, then (2) sub-select then (3) a cast where a simple count would suffice. It's probably not really going to be a performance bottleneck, just seems like an odd thing to do. Your general pattern of checking that the key is valid for every request is good.

Comment: @msanford OK.  Thank you for the link and the guidance.  I am new to SQL, and am working through best practices for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simply returning the count of rows from the database and validating that there exists `1` entry (or more than one, depending on how your data are structured).

Note that to mitigate against SQL Injection, you must use *parameter binding*, illustrated below; the library does not "automatically" protect against injection, [as per the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection) if you do not use parameter binding. Change `VarChar(100)` to whatever the column type is for those fields.

```
exports.validateKey = async function(req) {
  return await sql.connect(config.properties)
    .then(pool => pool.request()
        .input('user', sql.VarChar(100), req.header("username"))
        .input('key', sql.VarChar(100), req.header("apiKey"))
        .query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS valid FROM Login WHERE username = @user AND apiKey = @key')
        .then(response => result.recordset[0].valid === 1)
    )
}
```

Note that `validateKey` will return a Boolean *Promise*, so we've added [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to save modifying the route controller.

Note that I've removed the braces from most of the fat arrow functions: they're all one statement so they're [redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626753/single-line-to-multi-line-es6-fat-arrow-function).

*Caveat*: I can't actually try this, it's an educated guess from reading the documentation. I hope it helps.