# How to get certain data from async function?

Tags: node.js, function, async-await, discord.js, instagram

I'm trying to get data from the async function, however i'm unable to get it.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
IGclient
.login()
.then((data1) => {
  console.log('Data1: ', data1)
  IGclient
    .getProfile()
    .then(() => {
      (async () => {
        await IGclient.getUserByUsername({ username: "worldstar" })
      .then(res => console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges)) // it returns an array of your user's medias.
      console.log(res[0].shortcode);
      })()
    })
  })
})
```

response from `.then(res => console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges))`

```
Media:  [
  {
    node: {
      __typename: 'GraphVideo',
      id: '2662044547635514500',
      shortcode: 'CTxe2l2FIyE',
      dimensions: [Object],
      display_url: 'https://instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/241737702_603358297699631_5052269439534742639_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=nCAjzZxBpX8AX8dIRn2&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=68d55b1e54e94573e4a539c2dbd18688&oe=6141BC66&_nc_sid=7bff83',
      edge_media_to_tagged_user: [Object],
      fact_check_overall_rating: null,
      fact_check_information: null,
      gating_info: null,
      sharing_friction_info: [Object],
      media_overlay_info: null,
      media_preview: 'ABcqvg4CEE8gZ5J7f41TE5lbyicN1/z702GfMCux5XGT9Dz+lU1u08zfz8p46Zwev+fypW1C5svBxwx+nFFZ8l8cgLgiir0M9SpMJUUsoxHkZJHXP16ZqEzOUy2Cp4+YDJ7Z45AHbH61u3DCWGQdNv8A7KfX8KxokdpN8aK+R1fJUH15xk/mMnipL9CxDbJMPMZ9ufQcenfkZ+lFPe1l4aI7CB9eD/jRS+ZRoRRKDulPmMPX7o+i9P5mnAHPFQtVmHpSGEcIXOB1oq2lFID/2Q==',
      owner: [Object],
      is_video: true,
      has_upcoming_event: false,
      accessibility_caption: null,
      dash_info: [Object],
      has_audio: true,
      tracking_token: 'eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiOGU3NTM2OGY2NGVlNGE1YjkyZTE5OWM2NjlhYzY0ZWEyNjYyMDQ0NTQ3NjM1NTE0NTAwIiwic2VydmVyX3Rva2VuIjoiMTYzMTU2MjU0ODYzOHwyNjYyMDQ0NTQ3NjM1NTE0NTAwfDM1NjczOTU5MDN8ZDA4YTU1NmIzYzYxYzljYWFiMDlmZDg5ZmFlZmEwM2QwYmEwNWJiNzkxYjJjNTBmOWU5NzdlOTQzNTM2YmQ0YSJ9LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIifQ==',
      video_url: 'https://instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/241879045_655893848721915_3756581789983524987_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=MKV6lvykxUIAX8y1V2t&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61421A71&oh=5fd9789d322617de1064d5e1618ba214&_nc_sid=7bff83',
      video_view_count: 92970,
      edge_media_to_caption: [Object],
      edge_media_to_comment: [Object],
      comments_disabled: false,
      taken_at_timestamp: 1631560467,
      edge_liked_by: [Object],
      edge_media_preview_like: [Object],
      location: null,
      thumbnail_src: 'https://instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.210.540.540a/241737702_603358297699631_5052269439534742639_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=nCAjzZxBpX8AX8dIRn2&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=222d3ead453326c4392261439f345998&oe=6141AF70&_nc_sid=7bff83',
      thumbnail_resources: [Array],
      felix_profile_grid_crop: null,
      coauthor_producers: [],
      product_type: 'clips',
      clips_music_attribution_info: [Object]
    }
  },
```

I need to pick the `shortcode` from the response so i can somehow compare them, to detect if there was new post made and share it to the channel on discord..

`console.log(res[0].shortcode);` will return this...

```
console.log(res[0].shortcode);
                  ^

ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

How i can receive just the `shortcode` so then i can somehow compare them to detect new post? (Not sure even how to do that heheh.. will be another research...)

Update from comments:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
IGclient
.login()
.then((data1) => {
  console.log('Data1: ', data1)
  IGclient
    .getProfile()
    .then(() => {
      (async () => {
        await IGclient.getUserByUsername({ username: "worldstar" })
        .then(res => { console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges);       
        console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.Media[0].node.shortcode); })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

This won't return anything unfortunately.. not even first log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: If `console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges)` returns that object, then `res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.Media[0].node.shortcode` should get you the shortcode.

Comment: That's not working unfortunately @Brian K

Comment: Also, "res" is out of scope for when you're calling it. This is what your code should look like: ```.then(res => { 
      console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges));
      console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.Media[0].node.shortcode);
})```

Comment: If i add { after => i'm unable the close the code.. it won't work that way it seems..

Comment: Right now you're using a single-line arrow function, so `then(res => console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges))` logs out the res property you want, and then "res" variable goes out of scope. If you want access to the "res" variable, you must either return it from your current "then" statement and add another "then" statement afterward to process it (or await it), or you can use a multi-line arrow function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626753/single-line-to-multi-line-es6-fat-arrow-function (by adding curly braces to the arrow in your current "then" statement)

Comment: Check the edit i made, i tried it but it does not return anything.

Comment: Looks like you removed the () from the end of the (async () =>...) arrow function you create within the `then` statement. If you add that back in it should work.

Comment: (I don't recommend calling the async arrow function within your `then` statement by the way - if you return `IGclient.getUserByUsername({ username: "worldstar" })` in your outer `then` statement, then you should be able to chain another `.then` on the result of the promise returned by the promise returned by the previous `.then` statement, like this:
`.getProfile().then(() => {...}).then(() => ....)`

Comment: May you please post this as a regular answer? Cause these comments are not good for code sharing... Kind regards and thank you for trying helping me with this..

Comment: @RasmonT Just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues with your code

Your code has two issues that stop it from functioning properly:

1. You call upon the `res` variable after it has exited its scope.
2. You attempt to get your `res` object's `shortcode` property erroneously.

For issue number 1, there are a few ways to solve this, but the easiest would be to use a [multi-line arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626753/single-line-to-multi-line-es6-fat-arrow-function) in order to keep the `res` variable in scope while you call `console.log` on it a second time.

For issue number 2, saying `console.log(res[0].shortcode);` will most likely cause a type error to be thrown, as no property `0` exists on your `res` variable, so calling `res[0]` will return `undefined`. Trying to get a property from an `undefined` object will result in a `TypeError`. Based on the shape of the object you posted above, this should properly get the `shortcode` property from your `res` object:

`console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.Media[0].node.shortcode);`

You can probably get this working by doing something like this:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    IGclient
        .login()
        .then((data1) => {
            console.log('Data1: ', data1)
            IGclient
                .getProfile()
                .then(() => {
                    (async () => {
                        await IGclient.getUserByUsername({
                                username: "worldstar"
                            })
                            .then(res => {
                                console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges);
                                console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node.shortcode);
                            })()
                    })
                })
        })
})
```

#### Your usage of .then

The objects returned by the function given to `.then` are wrapped in a `Promise`, which allows you to chain `.then` statements together. This allows for cleaner, less nested code. This can be utilized to clean up your code, like so:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    IGclient
        .login()
        .then(data1 => {
            console.log('Data1: ', data1);
            return IGclient.getProfile();
        })
        .then(() =>
            IGclient.getUserByUsername({
                username: "worldstar"
            })
        ).then(res => {
            console.log('Media: ', res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges);
            console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node.shortcode);
        });
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have too many requests so seems my acc will be temporary locked (due testing) i will let you know once i try your code. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Brain K, i tried your code but however it's the same problem... 
console.log(res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.Media[0].node.shortcode);
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @RasmonT The JSON you posted in your question made me think that was the shape of your "res" object. Try this instead, then: res.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node.shortcode

Comment: @RasmonT just edited the answer to show the new "res" object shape.

Comment: @Brain K yes that made the trick! Thank you... now i will try to move on with this... Thank you so much for your help!